# How can I change the color of the current section in head of beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

I am trying to change the color of the current section separately from the other sections in the headline of beamer, generated through the `insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` command. However I cannot find the appropriate template, as `section in head/foot` changes the color of all sections and the non-current sections have a different shape. This is my MWE and obviously `current section in head/foot` does not exist.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{current section in head/foot}{fg=red}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}{Test}
Slide 1
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Test}
Slide 2
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\begin{frame}{Test}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\section{Third section}
\begin{frame}
Slide 4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Do you have an idea how I can format the current section differently from the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation I found, that there is no special color for it, the template `section in head/foot shaded` is used, but uses a mixed color of `bg` and `fg`. So to highlight the current section and select a different color, you need to redefine it:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{gray}\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}
```